# How secure is to use Rijndael symmetric encryption algorithm

Tags: algorithm, encryption, rijndael, symmetric

Please let us know how secure is Rijndael symmetric encryption algorithm.
The key is stored in web config file.

Comment: I would say, a lot, more than the people involved.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a programming question.

Comment: The fact that you are asking this question is an indicator that you probably shouldn't be directly using Rijndael in your code and should instead use a library that wraps the functionality for you.

Answer (score 5):

The Rijndael algorithm, in conjunction with safe configuration values (i.e. `AES`), is [very robust and secure](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/43427/16485). The only true measure of an encryption algorithm's security is its consistent and long-lived exposure to cryptanalysis and attempts to defeat it by many cryptographers. AES has thus far been successful at that task.

Storing the symmetric encryption key in source code is a [much bigger concern](https://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/best-practices-for-deploying-passwords-and-other-sensitive-data-to-aspnet-and-azure), and orders of magnitude more likely to be the cause of a data leak than Rijndael.